# How to stay in same page after submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently creating a subscription form using jQuery. My problem is I want to make this form stay in the same page after user click "SUBSCRIBE" button and when the process is successful, the text on button "SUBSCRIBE" change to "SUBSCRIBED".

Below is the code :

HTML:

```
<form action="http://bafe.my/sendy/subscribe" class="subcribe-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" />
    <input type="hidden" name="list" value="ttx7KjWYuptF763m4m892aI59A" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Landing" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan email anda" />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBSCRIBE<i class="fa fa-send fa-fw"></i></button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".subcribe-form").submit(function(){
    var validEmail = true;
    $("input.form-control").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("has-error");
            validEmail = false;
        } else{
            $(this).removeClass("has-error");
        }
    });
    if (!validEmail) alert("Please enter your email to subscribe");
    return validEmail;
});
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit strange to change the button text to "Subscribed"? Because it's still a button, so what happens if the user clicks it? Button text should be a verb. Anyway, rather than submitting the form you can make an Ajax request and then update the button text to "Subscribed" after the Ajax completes.

Comment: when using Ajax, be sure to change the type of the buttom from "submit" to "button"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the form submission but you also need to send the data to the server so for this you can use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ( see below code )

```
    $(".subcribe-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var validEmail = true;

    $("input.form-control").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("has-error");
            validEmail = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("has-error");
        }
    });

    if (!validEmail) { alert("Please enter your email to subscribe");
    }else {
//for valid emails sent data to the server
     $.ajax({
            url: 'some-url',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('.subcribe-form').serialize(),
            success: function(serverResponse) {
                       //... do something with the server Response...
                     }
        });
    }
    return validEmail;
    });
```

Comment: yes but you can use ajax to send the data to the server or you could submit the form from Js using $(".subcribe-form").submit();

Comment: If you submit the form anyway with `.submit()` then that brings you back to the same problem. Using Ajax is a good solution, but you need to explain that in your answer - if the OP already knew how to do that they wouldn't have asked the question...

Answer (score 1):

Add preventDefault so that form submission is prevented

```
$(".subcribe-form").submit(function(event){

event.preventDefault()
```

use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send your data to desired url

Comment: The data needs to be submitted (one way or another), the OP just wants to stay on the same page afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the form submission on the submit event, and return false:

if using AJAX : (With ajax you can either do that, or e.prenventDefault (), both ways work.)

```
$(".subcribe-form").submit(function(){
 ... // code here
 return false;
});
```

If using simple form :

```
 $(".subcribe-form").submit(function(e){
     ... // code here
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: How does the data get to the server if you prevent the submission?

Comment: In my comment there are two ways to remedy the problem if you use a normal form it is better to do an e.preventDefault (); Reason why by nature a button submit it makes a redirection by the action of the form, and if it uses ajax it is better to make a return false;

Comment: But you can see the OP's code. They're not using Ajax. (Yet.) If you want to suggest Ajax as a solution then you need to explain that in the answer, because as it currently stands you're preventing the data from being saved...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be easier to do it using PHP. If you do not want to use PHP, then you can ignore this answer.

If you want to give it a try, you can do the following:
1. Remove the action attribute from the form tag.
2. Write PHP code similar to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {  // "submit" is the name of the submit button
    onSubmit();
}

function onSubmit() {
    /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: If you remove the action attribute then how does the data get to the specific URL that is currently in the action attribute?

Comment: It doesn't. In my example the data stays on the page and you process it on that page.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I stay on the same page, a minimal example using jQuery:

```
<form id=f 
onsubmit="$.post('handler.php',$('#f').serialize(),d=>r.textContent+=rd.innerHTML=d);return false">
<textarea name=field1 id=t>user input here</textarea>
<input type=submit>
</form>
<textarea id=r width=80></textarea>
<div id=rd></div>
```

The key is to return false from the form *onsubmit* handler.